# Сортировка строк матрицы по количеству простых чисел в C++

Tags: c++, сортировка, матрицы, простые-числа

Имеется файл, в нём написаны 25 чисел квадратом 5х5 примерно таким образом: 
34 5 67 9 12
64 22 2 98 11
90 34 45 72 8
77 23 74 46 2
89 15 49 63 22 
Нужно вывести матрицу на экран консоли, отсортировав строки по количеству в них простых чисел.
Есть следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

/*В файле 25 чисел: матриц 5 на 5. Вывести на экран, отсортировав строки по количеству простых чисел */
bool isPrime(int b) // функция, которая определяет простое ли число
{
    for (int k = 2; k <= sqrt((double)b); k++)
        if (b%k == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}





int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Вывод матрицы из файла
    const int size = 5;
    int matrix [size][size];

    ifstream file("in.txt");

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {

        for (int j=0; j<5;  j++)
        {
        file>>matrix[i][j];
        cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    // Посчитаем количество простых чисел в каждой строке
    int max = 0, str = 0, num = 0, i=0, j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (isPrime(matrix[i][j]))
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (max <= num)
            {
                max = num;
                str = i;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        cout << matrix[str][j] << endl;
}
```

Проблема в том, что сортировки строк не происходит. Вывод программы следующий:

```
34 5 67 9 12
64 22 2 98 11
90 34 45 72 8
77 23 74 46 2
89 15 49 63 22
89
89
89
89
89
```

То есть, вывод матрицы(предусмотрено моим кодом), а потом просто 5 раз дублирует 1й элемент последней строки...А нужно, чтобы строки отсортировались по количеству в них простых чисел...кто-нибудь, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить часть кода отвечающую за сортировку??`

Comment: 2 - простое число

Comment: Вы можете словами описать, что делает Ваш код в двойном цикле, когда якобы считает количество простых чисел в каждой строке?

Comment: да, я знаю:) а программа должна посчитать количество простых чисел в каждой строке и вывести в начале строку, в которой их больше всего, потом ту, в которой их меньше, а последней - в которой их меньше всего или нет вообще. В общем, сортировка строк по признаку "количество простых чисел" в порядке убывания.

Comment: Нет, Вы не знаете украинской ночи. Где вообще в этом коде сортровка?

Comment: По идее, как было по задумке, мы пробегаем по массиву, и проверяем каждый элемент на простоту. Если он простой, мы делаем инкремент счётчика num. Потом ищем среди num'ов максимум, и строка, которой соответствует максимальный num, выводится, и так до конца. Я чувствую, что-то там вышло коряво, но пока никак не могу додумать, как скорректировать код и сам алгоритм...

Comment: Среди каких num-ов? Он у Вас один. Может Вам не надо пока такие сложные задания программировать?

Comment: То есть, нужно ввести 5 счётчиков для каждой строки и сделать 5 циклов? Надо, т.к. это домашнее задание.

Comment: возьмите для простоты размерность 3х3 и на бумажке распишите что у вас приосходит на каждой итерации, какие значения принимают переменные и какой в итоге происходит вывод. проблемные места сразу окажутся очевидными.

Comment: Откуда в последней строке кода взялось `j`?

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: Хочу подчеркнуть - никакой сортировки в Вашем коде нет.